# Textarea to variable: Spacing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm taking the content of a textarea and saving it in a variable. But I notice that when I save the content, the variable ignores the spacing (new lines). How do I fix this. I want the variable to store the structure of the text, with all the new lines and tabs. My code in which I save the content from the textarea is below:

```
let content = document.getElementById('content').value
```

The whole function is below:

```
function mail(){
    var options = document.getElementById('users').options
    let content = document.getElementById('content').value
    var emails = []
    var regex = /\*user\*/gi
    for(var i = 2; i < options.length; i++){
        emails.push(options[i].innerHTML)
        content = content.replace(regex, emails[i-2])
        window.open(`mailto:${emails[i-2]}?subject=To ${emails[i-2]}&body=${content}`)
    }     
}
```

Thanks!!! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In fact `JavaScript` does get all the value from the textarea including the newlines, but it's a `CSS` matter, if you just do a simple test, putting the retrieved value from the `textarea` into a `pre` tag or a `div` tag for example with `white-space: pre;` rule, you'll see the same content as the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, spaces and `new lines` are exists but because you put your `content` in `html` (`body{}`), they are invisible.

**some solutions:**

```
 let content = document.getElementById('content').value.replace(/\n/g,"<br/>").replace(/ ( +)/g,function(a,b){var s="", i=0; for(;i<b.length;i++)s+="&nbsp;"; return " "+s;});
```

or this:

```
let content = "<pre>"+document.getElementById('content').value+"</pre>"
```

or this:

```
let content = "<div style='white-space: pre'>"+document.getElementById('content').value+"</div>"
```

The above solutions were for when the body is `html`.

---

**Edit:**

I guess this will solve your problem:

```
let content = escape(document.getElementById('content').value);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It doesn't add a new line. It adds "<br/>" The other two don't work at all!

Answer (score 0):

The variable does contain new lines if new lines are entered in the textarea. Keep in mind that textarea will wrap the text to fit it so if you see wrapped text, that doesn't mean there is a new line character in the text.

```
<textarea id="content"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="msg()">

<script>
function msg() {
    let message = document.getElementById('content').value;
    alert(message);
}
</script>
```